# Creating new layers of individual polygons from existing layer of many using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile with 30 polygons. I want to create 30 shapefiles/layers from the original. I was doing this by selecting individual features and exporting them to a new layer.

Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: Do ctrl-drag to create a clone, use definition query after, e.g. fid = 0.

Comment: Split by attribute. That is the tool I need, it does exactly what I need.

Comment: indeed. Please feel free to answer your own question if you found the solution. Note that creating 30 shapefile (split by attribute) is a different task than creating 30 layers (@FelixIP comment)

Comment: Sorry about that, part of my problem is that I do not always know the correct terminology for what I am trying to achieve